# 0: request to https://play.hpccsystems.com:18010/WsSMC/Activity.json failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: visual-studio-code, ecl, hpcc

Every time I run an ECL file in VS Code, I am getting this error:
0:  request to https://play.hpccsystems.com:18010/WsSMC/Activity.json failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate. However, it was working fine until an hour ago.

[image]

I tried resetting the ECL extension and filling in the details in the launch.json file again but however it was of no use. I am not able to run the same file in ECL IDLE as well.